# Babel Plugin - How to parse JSX with attributes

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I'm writing a babel plugin to transform JSX code.

I can get an AST with the following code:

```
var babylon = require('babylon');

var code = '\
    <Outer>\
      <Inter />\
    </Outer>\
';

var ast = babylon.parse(code, {
  sourceType: 'module',
  plugins: ['jsx']
});
```

However, an error occurs with the following code:

```
var code = '\
    <Outer>\
      <Inter value=0 />\
    </Outer>\
';
```

The error is:

```
SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me share the answer that I've got at GitHub issue:

https://github.com/babel/babylon/issues/4

Comment: The reason why you didn't get an answer here is likely that you didn't choose good tags, so the question has low visibility. `babel` is not right tag anyway (read its tag description). `jsx` has probably also low volume, so at least adding `javascript` would be good.

Comment: Tag matters.. Thanks, @FelixKling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, this is not valid JSX. Attribute values must either be an expression (`value={0}`) or quoted (`value="0"`).